# Careers feature request: Open it for worldwide jobs

Tags: feature-request, jobs

My suggestion is to add some country information to the CV, not only location:

There should be a field with my current country and a field with the country, where I would like to work.

For example I'm living in Switzerland, and I'm looking for a job in the US.

So I would be much easier to select the corresponding candidates.

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't show you, but I entered "Zürich, Switzerland" as location. Even in the hint text it shows "London, England". Granted, this is not the Country, but just use "London, England UK". Works just fine.

"Zürich, Switzerland" will show up as "Zurich, Canton of Zurich Switzerland".
"Bichelsee-Balterswil, Switzerland" will be "Bichelsee-Balterswil, Canton of Thurgau Switzerland"

Use the Location field in personal information to say where your at, and the set of locations you want to work at in the section "Where do you want to work?" at the bottom.

Comment: Perhaps not the most intuitive way, but it will do the job. Thanks